# Reverse for 'data_bi_list' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

HELLO，I have googled this problem, but all didn't work.So please help me.
url.py:

```
url(r'^file_parse/$', file_parse),
url(r'^data_bi/(?P<data_list_id>\d+)/$', data_to_list, name = 'data_to_list'),
```

file_parse.html:

```
{% for item in uploadfile_info %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.uploaded_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.document }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <a href="{% url 'data_bi_list' item.id %}">{{ item.description }} </a>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

file_parse.py:

```
def file_parse(request):
    uploadfile_info = upload_document.objects.all()
    context = {'uploadfile_info': uploadfile_info}
    return render(request, 'logfile/file_parse.html', context)
```

data_bi.py:

```
def data_to_list(request, data_list_id):
    data_list = ES_device.objects.get(device_name=str(data_list_id))
    context = {'data_list': data_list}
    return render(request, 'logfile/data_bi.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to use `'data_to_list'` instead of `'data_bi_list'` in your template? You url `'data_to_list'`.

```
...
<a href="{% url 'data_to_list' item.id %}"> 
...
```

Comment: yeah, my fault, Thanks a lot